# Does python interpreter reuse results for efficiency?

Tags: python, interpreter

```
#L is a very large list
A = [x/sum(L) for x in L]
```

When the interpreter evaluates this, how many times will sum(L) be calculated? Just once, or once for each element?

Comment: once for every element. You should store the sum in some other variable and use that in the expression.

Comment: Even in a heavily statically-optimized language, you would want to compute `sum(L)` outside the loop rather than relying on the optimizer to perform loop-invariant code motion. Who knows when some incredibly subtle change would prevent the optimizer from recognizing the optimization opportunity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list comprehension executes the expression *for each iteration*.

`sum(L)` is executed for each `x in L`. Calculate it once *outside* the list comprehension:

```
s = sum(L)
A = [x/s for x in L]
```

Python has no way of knowing that the outcome of `sum(L)` is stable, and cannot optimize the call away for you.

`sum()` could be rebound to a different function that returns random values. The elements in `L` could implement `__add__` methods that produce side effects; the built-in `sum()` would be calling these. `L` itself could implement a custom `__iter__` method that alters the list in-place as you iterate, affecting both the list comprehension *and* the `sum()` call. Any of those hooks could rebind `sum` or give `x` elements a `__div__` method that alters `sum`, etc.

In other words, Python is too dynamic to accurately predict expression outcomes.

Comment: What a bummer then. The interpreter could be a bit smarter.

Comment: @user2460978: How could it be smarter? You can rebind `sum` to a different function *at any time* to alter `L` in-place or return random values on each call. Python is *highly dynamic* and it cannot know that the outcome will be for each call.

Comment: @user2460978: Not much smarter without some sort of just-in-time compiler. Maybe the elements of `L` implement an `__add__` method that sends spam emails when invoked, and this list comprehension is an incredibly misguided way to invoke the spammer code. Some Python variants have a JIT, but CPython doesn't.

Comment: PyPy might be able to optimize that away.

Comment: @Albert: sure, at the cost of having to instrument to detect when wrong.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Of course not. PyPy will never change the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I would opt for Martijn's approach, but thought I'd point out that you can (ab)use a `lambda` with a default argument and a `map` if you wanted to retain a "one-liner", eg:

```
L = range(1, 10)
A = map(lambda el, total=sum(L, 0.0): el / total, L)
```